# How do I generate a Guava ByteSource from a Path?

Tags: java, file-io, guava

I am trying to hash the file at a `Path` using Guava. I cannot use the `File` class because this is not supported by JimFS.

If I had a `File`, I would use this Guava method:

```
public static ByteSource asByteSource(File file)
```

Is there an equivalent for `Path`?

If not, how can I implement one?

Comment: Are you using `java.nio.file.Path`? Then simply use [`Path.toFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile--).

Comment: Path::toFile won't work if the Path is for a file system other than local disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only can use `Path`, then have a look at [`MoreFiles::asByteSource`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/MoreFiles.java#L83).

Comment: Works a treat. I wish more libraries would use `Path` instead of `File`.